# Ruby - Arrays - What would be a smart way to do this:

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
if country == "Switzerland"
      icon_link = "ch"
    elsif country == "Poland"
      icon_link = "pl" 
    elsif country == "Germany"
      icon_link = "de"
    elsif country == "Spain"
      icon_link = "sp"
    elsif country == "Japan"
      icon_link = "jp"
    elsif country == "Kazakhstan"
      icon_link = "kz"  
    elsif country == "Hong Kong"
     icon_link = "hk" 
    elsif country == "China"
      icon_link = "cn"
    end
    image_tag("icons/flags/#{icon_link}.png",options)
```

I'm guessing I would need to create an array and use the keys but don't figure out how to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely want a Hash:

```
# do this part once to load your hash
countryCode = {
  "Switzerland" => "ch",
  "Germany"     => "de",
  # ...
}

# generate the image_tag call
if( countryCode.has_key?( country ) )
  image_tag( "icons/flags/#{countryCode[country]}.png",options)
else
  # country code not in your hash
end
```

Comment: +1 for has_key :) I always forget that until it bites me.. #n00b

Comment: I like this answer because it does not try to generate the tag `icons/flags/.jpg` for illegal countries!

Comment: Another option is to use fetch method which can specify a default value is the key is not in the hash: `countryCode.fetch(country, 'default')`.

Comment: Thanks Digikata and everyone else who took the time to answer.

Comment: @James Another way to set a default is with the hash itself: `countryCode.default = 'default'` or with the `Hash.new { |hash,idx| ... }` initialization.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, a Hash can do this. In other languages, similar functionality is sometimes called an "associative array". Basically they take a key (in your case the country) and a value (the locale code, such as 'cn').

Declare the hash:

```
country_codes = {"Switzerland" => "ch",      "Poland" => "pl", etc.... }
                    / key \     / value \     / key \   /value\
```

With the hash declared above:

```
country_codes["Switzerland"] => "ch"
```

Then you use it like:

```
image_tag("icons/flags/#{country_codes[country]}.png",options)
```

See: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/basictutorial.htm#_Hashes

Answer (score 1):

```
 icon_links = { "Switzerland" => "ch",
                "Poland"=> "pl",
                "Germany" => "de",
                "Spain" => "sp",
                "Japan" => "jp",
                "Kazakhstan" => "kz",  
                "Hong Kong" => "hk", 
                "China" => "cn"}
 icon_link = icon_links[country]
 image_tag("icons/flags/#{icon_link}.png",options)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your special need, I would recommend the Hash-solution in the other answers.

As an alternative you may use case instead the if-elsif-construct.

```
case country 
  when "Switzerland"
    icon_link = "ch"
  when "Poland"
    icon_link = "pl" 
  when "Germany"
    icon_link = "de"
  when "Spain"
    icon_link = "sp"
  when "Japan"
    icon_link = "jp"
  when "Kazakhstan"
    icon_link = "kz"  
  when "Hong Kong"
   icon_link = "hk" 
  when "China"
    icon_link = "cn"
end
```

You can integrate case also as paramter:

```
image_tag("icons/flags/%s.png" % case country 
  when "Switzerland"
    "ch"
  when "Poland"
    "pl" 
  when "Germany"
    "de"
  when "Spain"
    "sp"
  when "Japan"
    "jp"
  when "Kazakhstan"
    "kz"  
  when "Hong Kong"
   "hk" 
  when "China"
    "cn"
  else
    "dummy"
end, options)
```